# startActivity intent is crashing on app upgrade in android 10 & above

Tags: android

Below is my code bit.

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/<filename>.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(installIntent);
```

Logs attached below.

> 2021-05-12 13:40:27.167 6451-6451/Testpackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: Testpackage , PID: 6451
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 }
> at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2051)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1849)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5892)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:5867)
> at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:8616)
> at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1101)
> at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1080)
> at com.vitamap.medge.ui.PrefsFragment.handleUpgdPrefClick(PrefsFragment.java:549)
> at com.vitamap.medge.ui.PrefsFragment.lambda$onCreate$0(PrefsFragment.java:105)
> at com.vitamap.medge.ui.-$$Lambda$PrefsFragment$ptok941-PomzwJdbFAOuP_uSPDs.onUpgdPrefClick(Unknown Source:2)
> at com.vitamap.medge.ui.base.UpgradeCheckPref.onClick(UpgradeCheckPref.java:61)
> at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1163)
> at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:260)
> at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
> at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1190)
> at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3198)
> at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4116)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please always try to add crash logs as well, it helps to debug little faster

Comment: logs has been updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't attached any logs but analysing your code I think that this crash might be related to privacy changes in Android 10 (file access). You can read more about this here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage

Answer (score -1):

This is Due to In android 10 and Above you can directly access the external storage just add this line inside the **Application** Tag in AndroidManifest.xml file **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**  .

Comment: `requestLegacyExternalStorage` only works on Android 10 and 11 if the targetAPI of the app is set to API level 29. As Google only accepts such apps until August 2021 this solution is more a temporary workaround (with known expiration date) than a real solution.

Comment: Hi, still i see same issue